# NSIS: 'Could not find symbol'

Tags: dll, nsis

I am trying to make a custom DLL for my NSIS script and almost everything is going smoothly.

I've created a DLL file that exports the desired functions, and verified that those functions have been exported (using dumpbin):
[Dumpbin results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs1FB.png)

I've placed the .dll file in the plugins directory and called one of the functions in the script using `DLLName::FunctionName`: [Picture of the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62dOA.png)

The compiler "sees" my DLL in the plugins directory and is able to attach the function I'm calling to it:
[Compiler View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5mgg.png)

However, when I run the installer, I get the message `Could not find symbol: <Function Name>` for every function I call from that DLL:
[Here's the error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLiHC.png)

I'm not sure why it's having trouble at this last step. Can anyone help me out? I greatly appreciate any input.

Comment: GetProcAddress is failing, not sure why.

Comment: I figured out the problem- The tool I'm using to export the functions requires a name parameter to name the exports correctly.